# loading locations on a mapview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

i need to add a location to my map, i get the locations coordinates from my firebase storage by this

```
  func download(){
    var ref = Firebase(url:"https://sweltering-inferno-4285.firebaseio.com/Locations/Shop/1")
    ref.childByAppendingPath("Locations/Shop/1")
    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    println(snapshot.value)
    self.shopName = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Shop_Name") as String
    self.Location = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Location") as String
    self.Long = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Longitude") as String
    self.Lat = snapshot.value.objectForKey("Latitude") as String

    var x = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self.Lat)?.doubleValue
    var y = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self.Long)?.doubleValue

    self.coor = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: x!,longitude: y!)

        }, withCancelBlock: { error in
            println(error.description)
    })
}
```

i then create an object "artwork" from the attributes above and add it to an array of objects

```
func loadInitialData(){
    let artwork = Artwork(title: self.shopName,
        locationName: self.Location,
        discipline: "Sculpture",
        coordinate: coor)
    self.artworks.append(artwork)
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.artworks) }
```

and form the viewdidload i call the functions download() then loadinitialdata(),
the problem is the function finishes and the view is loaded before the data is downloaded and that leads to an empty map.
Ps i am sure that is the problem as i tested the code above with a hardcoded date and it appeared on the map.
what is need is how to make the function wait for the data to be loaded and then load the map.
i use apple's mapkit

Comment: You need to create the annotation and add it to the map in the completion block (the `withBlock:`) closure.

Comment: sorry i am new to swift

Answer (score 0):

You should call loadInitialData() method inside the withBlock: closure of ref.observeEventType() and not inside viewDidLoad() because self.coor will be nil in viewDidLoad. I'm assuming Artwork inherits from MKAnnotation which needs a valid coordinate to know which position it should appear when added to the map.

Answer (score 0):

I am too agree with ahmed Onawale to use completion block to show annotation you should go with his answer.
but if you don't get success in implementing the completion block(that is never gonna happen after certain tries) just create one separate func to show notation on map call the above created function when you got success response from server with data or location.